# Is it possible to generate similar animation show in the video with AN in 2.9

Tags: animation-nodes

Is it possible to generate same result as shown in the video with blender 2.9?
Ive searched for hours and don't find anything that connects me to similar solution but no result. Maybe someone could show me the road. Im a starter in AN.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4wcSW-e_Pg&ab_channel=JacquesLucke

Comment: Here is version for 2.83 https://animation-nodes.com ... so it should be working for 2,9 as well ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in newer version of Animation nodes. Before doing this type of animation we have to prepare our objects. Make sure that the objects have loose parts(we can't do this on a single mesh). Each objects should have appropriate orgin for better looking animation.

Let's look at this example, I have a cycle object which is composed of multiple objects. So i put everything into a collection 'cycle' for ease of use.

Next step is storing the current transforms(location,rotation,scale) of every objects into a ID Key. This is important because when using nodes like `Object Transform Output` or `Object Matrix Output` will set objects transforms to a default value.

We can create ID key by:
[image]

The ID key can be accessed inside nodetree by:
[image]

Next step is driving the scale and rotation of objects with a falloff. There are different types of falloffs are available in animation nodes. Here i used Delay falloff for demonstration.
[image]

[See Animation nodes Documentation for more info](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/object/object_id_key/)

Comment: Also worth looking this video :https://youtu.be/TYkPvFLDBNI